# Azure Multifactor authentication in java desktop application

Tags: java, adal, multi-factor-authentication

I need to authenticate via azure ad in my application. I found this example code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless but my azure is configured with MFA and I get this error:

```
{"error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: 643e8491-904a-4cea-b2a6-c720dda97f00\r\nCorrelation ID: 946f5469-c2b3-4de4-8c92-ab73aabc13d3\r\nTimestamp: 2018-08-27 12:59:25Z","error":"interaction_required"}
```

And now I'm not sure how to provide verification code to my application. Does anyone has any example code, wiki how to use it with MFA?

Answer (score -1):

[This sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect) should help you. It uses OpenID connect with a Java application.

As for your error, in AAD, if you do an initial login in one location, and then login from another location, there are conditions on the AD that flag this as "risky activity".

So for your account there is a "moved to a new location" flag that can get set, automatically triggering the need for MFA.  If you do face this, check the conditional access locations in Azure and see if you can clear the flag.  (Or set up the original account with named locations in place.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-locations